# Additional query for each item?

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-structures

I have a really long list of **items**. I.e:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT i.id
            ORDER by i.id DESC LIMIT 0, 200"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ $num_row++;
}
```

Outputs:

[ITEM 1] [ITEM 2] [ ITEM 3] ... [ITEM 200]

Here's the thing. I need to check for each item if the the **User** has **Liked** the item. Do I have to launch an additional query for each Row of the first item query? We're talking about 200 queries... Is there away to join this query into the first one?

I was thinking of structuring the "like" table as so:

```
id, item_ref, user_id
----------------------
1,     1,     5
1,     5,     5
1,     3,     5
```

Should display, when logged in as user_id 5:

[ITEM 1 liked] [ITEM 2] [ITEM 3 liked] [ITEM 4] [ITEM 5 liked] ... [ITEM 200]

Any tips?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join onto the like table and use that to see if there is a like for a particular user. You miss out a bit of your query but something like (assuming you use the like table you mention):

```
SELECT i.id, l.id IS NOT NULL AS liked
FROM item i
LEFT JOIN likes l ON (i.id = l.item_ref AND l.user_id = YOURUSERIDHERE)
ORDER by i.id DESC LIMIT 0, 200
```

`liked` in the results is whether or not there is a like for the given user.

Comment: That seems to work great! BTW $row['liked'] is giving me a "1" when true and "0" when false, is that correct?

Comment: @James Yep that's correct. MySQL considers zero as false and non zero as true. PHP will treat these correctly.